# Java.lang.NullPointerException (During Configuration) in Openam

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, openam, forgerock

I am new to openam and I am trying to create and deploy a new OpenAM Tomcat instance within an already existing OpenAM deployment.

#### Things Which is done and is working fine:

1.Tomcat Installed.(I am able to ping Apache Tomcat home page.)

**Tomcat version:7.0.62**

Placed openam.war file(**Version:13.5.0**) and placed into webapps folder of tomcat.

3.Able to hit openam in my browser.

4.Created new configuration and filled all the Configuration Store and User Store details along with other details.

5.Created Configuration ... and this error popped up.

[image: NullPointerException]
Everything was working good in my first go but I messed some thing in realm  and so I deleted my **openam** folder and **.openamcfg** folder and restarted the Tomcat server and got the error

> Java.lang.NullPointerException

Googled it and this time I deleted even openam folder from tomcat/webapps and restarted the server and done above steps and this time I got the error:

> AdminTokenAction: FATAL ERROR: Cannot obtain Application SSO token

Now I am getting null exception ,
My Install.log file looks like:

```
    Checking license acceptance...License terms accepted.
License, legal-notices/license.txt, has been accepted.
License Hash: a5GIoWOZQaGncrUaRgtjo5kmm7g=.
Checking configuration directory /home/admin/openam....Success.
Reinitializing system properties....Done
Configuring server instance....Done
Setting up monitoring authentication file.AMSetupServlet.processRequest: errorjava.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.getBootStrapURL(BootstrapCreator.java:189)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.update(BootstrapCreator.java:104)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.updateBootstrap(BootstrapCreator.java:82)
        at com.sun.identity.common.configuration.ServerConfigXMLObserver.update(ServerConfigXMLObserver.java:108)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.processRequest(AMSetupServlet.java:517)
        at com.sun.identity.config.wizard.Wizard.createConfig(Wizard.java:301)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.click.util.ClickUtils.invokeMethod(ClickUtils.java:3317)
        at org.apache.click.util.ClickUtils.invokeListener(ClickUtils.java:2088)
        at org.apache.click.control.AbstractControl$1.onAction(AbstractControl.java:228)
        at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(ActionEventDispatcher.java:259)
        at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvents(ActionEventDispatcher.java:236)
        at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvents(ActionEventDispatcher.java:180)
        at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.performOnProcess(ClickServlet.java:746)
        at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.processAjaxPageEvents(ClickServlet.java:1860)
        at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.processPage(ClickServlet.java:559)
        at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.handleRequest(ClickServlet.java:383)
        at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.doGet(ClickServlet.java:276)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditContextFilter.doFilter(AuditContextFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Dumping all configuration parameters...

Request Parameters:
acceptLicense = true
actionLink = createConfig
ADMIN_CONFIRM_PWD = #########
ADMIN_PWD = #########
AM_ENC_KEY = #########
AMLDAPUSERPASSWD = #########
AMLDAPUSERPASSWD_CONFIRM = #########
BASE_DIR = /home/admin/openam
COOKIE_DOMAIN = 
DATA_STORE = dirServer
DIRECTORY_ADMIN_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_JMX_PORT = -1 ...
...
```

Edit: I Deleted openam folder inside work/Catalina/localhost/ also deleted openam folder and openamcfg and again restarted everything. Still I am getting,

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException

I did my research on web but unable to figure out what could be the possible reason. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you are using an external configuration store with your AM instance. Before trying to install AM for the second time, you should make sure that the previous configuration data is removed from the directory server, or you should at least use a different root suffix.

Comment: It worked when I removed previous configuration dn and recreated it.

Comment: I am running into the same issue, how do you remove and recreate the configuration?